# How to set C++ language standard in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

Today we worked on a piece of code that requires either C++14 or C++17.  My colleague used C++Builder for the code editing, and also wanted to try to compile the code piece with it.

We could not find the setting where one sets the C++ language standard. What we found by googling was that C++builder has a "classic compiler" that supports only parts of C++11 and a "clang-based compiler" that supports up to C++17. We found a check box for enabling/disabling the "classic compiler" in the project settings, but no project setting for selecting the language standard explicitly (to switch between C++14 and C++17). Is there something like that? Where?

The version that we have is C++Builder 10.2.

We also tried to explicitly set an additional compiler option -std=c++14 for the clang-based compiler but this option was rejected ("unknown value c++14").

Comment: If you can pass flags to the compiler, try passing it `--version` or `-v`. The output will tell you which which compiler your IDE is using. You can then look up what the language support for that compiler version is.

Comment: https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/new-in-rad-studio-10-3-c-17-asynchronous-c-code-completion-and-more

Comment: It has a Clang compiler and the usual borland classic compiler, basically try Clang compiler (by not cheching use classic compiler in the settings) if it doesnt work u may have some dependencies (include errors) or some missing lib paths if it is a linking unresolved external (lastly u can try checking the classic compiler if none of the above works).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hans Passant has posted a comment to my question which links to [New in RAD Studio 10.3: C++17, asynchronous C++ code completion, and more](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/new-in-rad-studio-10-3-c-17-asynchronous-c-code-completion-and-more), thank you.

From this link I learn:

1. C++ Builder 10.2 does not include any support for C++14 nor C++17.
2. C++ Builder 10.3 supports C++17 only when compiling 32 bit windows binaries. Support for C++14 is only available in the sense that C++17 is "with some small exceptions, a superset" of C++14.  Which means, you cannot select the desired language standard used for compilation.
3. C++ Builder 10.4 seems to support C++17 also for 64 bit windows. It is unclear if and how the language standard to use can be selected.

Comment: "*10.3 supports C++17 only when compiling 32 bit windows binaries*" - Read again more carefully. The blog post you linked to, and [the DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers) too, both say the same Clang version 5.0 is used in Win32 and Win64. Only C++17 **language features** are not in Win64 yet, but C++17 **library features** are (`std::string_view`, etc).

Comment: "*you cannot select the desired language standard used for compilation*" - actually, you can, per the [10.3 "What's New"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/What's_New#Backwards_compatibility) release notes: "The Win32 compiler defaults to C++17 for all projects. However, in the Project Options > C++ Compiler page, **you can choose to use an earlier language standard**, including C++14, C++11, and even C++98/03."

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the correction about standard selection, edited that in. I had noticed the distiction between C++17 language vs library features but left that out because in summary it means C++17 is not supported.

Comment: 10.4 Sydney supports Clang v5.0 for both Win32 and Win64 - so both support C++14 and C++17. Quoting from the DocWiki:
The Clang-enhanced compilers for Win32 and Win64 (bcc32c/bcc32x and bcc64) implement all of the ISO C++17 standard.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Modern_C%2B%2B_Features_Supported_by_RAD_Studio_Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers

Comment: @RemyLebeau I had a chance to try and find the C++ language standard settings in an instance of C++ Builder 10.3 today. I could not find any C++14/17/11/03 settings under Project Options > C++ Compiler for a 32 bit windows project. Rolled back my previous change because of this.

Comment: @T.Herzke You'll have to type it in yourself [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGQ3j.png). 10.3.3 even recognizes `-std=c++2a`

Answer (score 3):

The ISO C++, 10.4 Sydney C++Builder and Clang version information is as follows:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers

```
Compiler    Platform        Clang Version   LLVM Version
BCC32C      32-bit Windows  5.0             5.0
BCC32X      32-bit Windows  5.0             5.0
BCC64       64-bit Windows  5.0             5.0
BCCIOSARM   32-bit iOS      3.3             3.3
BCCIOSARM64 64-bit iOS      3.3             3.5
BCCAARM     Android         3.3             3.3
```

https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Clang 3.3 and later implement all of the ISO C++ 2011 standard.

Clang 3.4 and later implement all of the ISO C++ 2014 standard.

Clang 5 and later implement all the features of the ISO C++ 2017 standard.

David Millington, Product Manager for C++Builder, also keeps the Embarcadero C++Builder information updated on the C++ Reference site at
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

You can look at the different ISO C++ language releases to see what many compilers support in their compiler releases.